# How change language of interface in itunes connect

Tags: app-store-connect

I had English language in iTunes Connect, but today it's changed to russian (I'm from Russia) and I cant find where to change the interface's language back to English (Russian localized - bad).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Found that very frustrating too (I'm Russian as well). It based on your "preferred language" settings in browser. If you use Chrome, it can be found there **chrome://settings/languages**, move "English" upper. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something has changed over the time, but the previous approach didn't work for me. My solution (macOS Sierra):

- Open "System Preferences"
- Open "Language & Region". There is list of "Preferred language" on the left panel. Click on the button "+" under the list and add English language as primary.
- Reboot you mac.

Comment: Yeah, it was 2015 :) ty

Comment: Didn't help either.. Russian language is like nightmare - popups everywhere

Comment: It doesn't work. Tested on Google Chrome. It takes language priority from your web-browser and not your macOS!

Answer (score 0):

Access link https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/en => It will auto switch language English

Comment: No, this is wrong.